# Footer Unordered list overlapping issue

Tags: css, list, footer, overlapping, unordered

I'm having an issue with my footer that I've been trying to figure out for some time now. My unordered list is set to float right but that's causing it to go out of the parent div for some reason.

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong ?

**Issue Screenshot:**

[image]

```css
.footer-content {
  width: 980px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
}
.footer-content p {
  padding-top: 9px;
}
.footer-content ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.footer-content ul li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.footer-content ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0066cc;
}
.footer-content ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.footer-content ul li a:visited {
  color: #0066cc;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-content">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 - 2016 Nexishost, inc. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `float: right;` to position your `ul`, you will need to `float: left;` the `p` element.

The reason is that a `p` element is a block element. Thus, anything next to the element itself will be moved to it's own line. You have to essentially take out the 'full width' that is assumed by the `p` element itself.

To learn a bit more about block level and inline level elements, check out [this resource](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp).

Comment: I appreciate it very much, worked really well. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardRodgers no problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

UL is also a block element (just like p). Since you are using float on the list item instead of the UL block itself, another option is to change the display of your ul by adding display:inline.

```
.footer-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  display:inline;
}
```

Edit: Added [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umy57nrp/). You will have to scroll horizontally to view (width is 980px)

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help as well.